# Turn integer into date

Tags: r, datetime

When I turn the date vector into a dataframe the dates turn into a integer. This integer has a very strange format and I can not understand how to turn it in to a date (including seconds).

```
vdates <- seq(c(ISOdate(2018,10,01)), by = "3 sec", length.out = 200000)

dfDates <- as.data.frame((matrix(vdates))) 
dfDates$id <- 1:nrow(dfDates)
colnames(dfDates) <- c("Dates", "Id")
```

Comment: Your problem is the use of `matrix`. A matrix cannot contain objects of class `POSIXct`. It is also totally unnecessary here. Just do `dfDates <- data.frame(Dates = vdates, Id = 1:length(vdates))`.

Comment: The problem is not the call to `as.data.frame`, but the `matrix` which does not preserve the date class apparently. You could convert it back for example with `as.POSIXct.numeric(dfDates$Dates, origin = "1970-01-01")`.